TSelectionPoint color
TSelection has a Color property that enables us to change the colors easily.
TSelectionPoint does not have a Color property.  I want to change the color of the circle even when it is not active.
sp1.OnApplyStyleLookup := DoApplyStyleLookup;
sp1.ApplyStyleLookup; 

procedure TForm1.DoApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject); 
  var Obj: TFmxObject; 
begin   
  showmessage( (sender as TSelectionPoint).Children.count.tostring );   
  for var StyleRes in (sender as tSelectionPoint).Children do   
  begin
    ShowMessage(StyleRes.Name); // Display the name of the style resource   
  end;

  Obj := (Sender as TSelectionPoint).FindStyleResource('background');  // is background correct?
  if Assigned(Obj) and (Obj is TShape) then
    (Obj as TShape).Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Red; // Change to your desired color 
end;

This does not work. Any thoughts?  Do I need to create a TStylebook etc, or there is a built in style in TSelectionPoint?

I checked the TSelectionPoint code and it doesn't seem possible with a style. If you look at the Paint method of TSelectionPoint in FMX.Objects you'll see that it uses a canvas to draw the circle and the colors are hardcoded. You could create a component that inherits from TSelectionPoint and overrides paint and pass circle color via your own property.
